# How to pass data to method from a vue element iteration

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am developing an invoice system in laravel vuejs. I am trying to pass data to the method from a form. In this form, I have used iteration to add/remove input text/select fields. In order to Iterate I have used v-model of these inputs. Now these v-models fail to pass data. When I console, I see they are empty.

I am sharing codes of that form :

For Iteration

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(item,k) in inputs" :key="k">
     <div class="row mb-2">
         <div class="col-md-3">
             <select class="form-control" v-model="item.product_id" 
             @change="getProductCost()">
                 <option value="">Select Product</option>
                 <option v-for="(product, i) in products" :key="i" :value="product.id">{{ 
                 product.product_name }}</option>
             </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" v- 
               model="item.quantity" @keyup="getProductCost">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Total" v- 
               model="item.total">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
               <span>
                    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle text-danger" @click="removeElement(k)" v- 
                    show="k || ( !k && inputs.length > 1)"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle text-success ml-4" @click="addElement(k)" v- 
                    show="k == inputs.length-1"></i>
               </span>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

From script, I need to pass data (item : {}) to getProductCost() method

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        allerrors : [],
        
        inputs : [{
            product_id : '',
            quantity : '',
            total : '',
        }],

        item : {
                product_id : '',
                quantity : '',
                total : '',
        }    
    }
},

getProductCost() {
    axios.get('/api/product-cost? 
    product_id='+this.item.product_id+'&&quantity='+this.item.quantity, 
    this.data).then(response => {
           this.data.total_product_price = response.data
    })
},

addElement() {
   this.inputs.push({
        product_id : '',
        quantity : '',
        total : ''
   })
},

removeElement (index) {
   this.inputs.splice(index, 1)
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually you are overwriting the scope of item in the forloop.
I could imagine, that you just have to rename this line

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(item,k) in inputs" :key="k">
```

to something like this:

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(input,k) in inputs" :key="k">
```

and check for renaming the coresponding references aswell.

Edit 1:
You can look here for the vuejs way to handle dynamic data bindings and adjust it to your case: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-make-form-elements-dynamic-in-vue-js/

Comment: I tried with this earlier, but It triggers all iterated input fields with the same value

Comment: @azim makes sense to me since you map all input fields to one item. Every Iteration should have a own "saving space". In the way you implemented it here one change changes everything.

Comment: is there any other way to make it ?

Comment: @azim yes, but that is a whole new chapter. I will not shadow code your project but I attached a worthful source in the edit of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have to do it anyhow lol.